# Transform: scale using Viewport Units

Tags: css, transform, viewport-units

I want to use a transform: scale where my width changes to 80vw and my height is auto. So this is what i want = `transform: scale(80vw, auto);`. Unfortunately, this doesnt work. Is there another way to get this effect. Preferably without using javascript.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var range = 1 / 400;
var vw = range * Math.min(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vw-scale', `${vw}`);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vw-scale', `${range * Math.min(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)}`);
});
```

```css
.scale-element {
  width: 400px;
  transform: scale(var(--vw-scale));
  transform-origin: left top;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scale-element">
  <h1>Test title</h1>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed, et. Deserunt officiis provident quod perferendis dolore dolores enim sint veniam ea odio ratione, repudiandae distinctio, aliquid possimus commodi cupiditate voluptas!
  </p>
</div>
```

Even though the calc function is not used directly, it works close to it.
for test and resize screen you should view it in full page option.

Answer (score 0):

A transform Scale() does't take a unit. it is more like a ratio so scaleX(0.5) will scale the div to half and so on.

```css
.normal{
 background: red;
 }
 .scaled{
  width:100vw;
  transform:scaleX(0.8);
  background:green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="normal">
  normal
</div>
<div class="scaled">
  scaled
</div>
```